# Cannot find module 'fs-extra' npm

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, npm-install, solidity

using truffle@5.3.2, ganache@2.5.4, node@10.19.0, npm@7.10.0

**for blockchain developers**

```
$ sudo truffle migrate --reset
```

works fine...consume gas from fake account in ganache.

```
 $ sudo truffle test

     Using network 'development'.

Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/external "fs-extra":1:18)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/updated.js:33:26)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/profiler.js:20:19)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/index.js:3:18)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/compile-common/dist/src/index.js:25:18)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/debugger/lib/session/index.js:31:1)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/debugger/lib/debugger.js:4:1)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at Object.call (/home/amal/work/truffle/packages/debugger/debugger.js:1:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:83:10
    at factory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/debugger.js:1:1152)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:3:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
Truffle v5.3.2 (core: 5.3.2)
Node v10.19.0
```

**Measure Taken**

1.

```
    $ sudo npm ls fs-extra
 pet-shop@1.0.0 /home/phenomenal/blockchain    

    +-- fs-extra@3.0.1
    
          -- lite-server@2.6.1
    
          -- browser-sync@2.26.14
    
        `-- fs-extra@3.0.1 deduped
```

2. `*npm install -g npm-reinstall*`
3. `*npm install -g npm@latest*`

But nothing works!!!

Here's the test file **election.js**

```
var Election = artifacts.require('./Election.sol');

contract("Election",function(accounts){

    it("Initializes with two candidates",function(){            //Mocha framework
        return Election.deployed().then(function(instance){
            return instance.candidatesCount();
        }).then(function(count){
            asserts equal(count,2); //Chai Library Function
        });
    });

});
```

**Election.sol** file

```
contract Election {
    
    //Model of Candidate
    struct Candidate{
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    //Store Candidate
    //Fetch Candidate
    mapping(uint => Candidate) public listOfCandidates;

    //Store Candidate Count
    uint public candidatesCount;


    //construtor
    constructor() public {
        addCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addCandidate("Candidate 2");
    }
    
    function addCandidate(string memory _name) private{
        candidatesCount++;
        listOfCandidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount,_name,0);
    }   
}
```

**Package.json file**

```
 {
  "name": "pet-shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "truffle.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Please help If require I would send you the complete project or required files.

Comment: share your `package.json` file

Comment: My guess is that `sudo truffle` runs the globally installed `truffle` and looks for the `fs-extra` in the global dependencies (where it doesn't exist)... Have you tried installing and running the whole thing without the `-g` option and without `sudo`? ... A workaround might be `npm install -g fs-extra` but this is not a clean approach.

Comment: As per conversation Package.json file has been added

Comment: Thanks @PetrHejda .... its working fine now.
using **npm install -g fs-extra** installs it globally and things working just fine.